# ajax post security in laravel?

Tags: security, laravel-5.1, ajaxform

I am developing an application in laravel 5.1, I need to use sensitive user data and i was wondering about security when using ajax posts instead of a standard  post. is it recommended using ajax, is there a way of performing some kind of protected ajax posts? Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel 5.1 you can use the [HTTP Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) in order to create something similar to the filters of older version.

**1: Define Middleware**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class BeforeMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Check all your ajax stuff

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Inside the definition you can check wheter the request is Ajax, or other (have a look at the [Class Reference](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html)) and define, for example, if the user has authorization to that specific route.

**2: Assign middleware to routes**

```
// Within App\Http\Kernel Class...

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'myMiddleware' => \Path\To\The\MiddleWare::class,
];
```

**3: use the middleware key in the route options array**

```
Route::post('your/route', ['middleware' => 'myMiddleware', function () {
    //
}]);
```